# How to pass output from one function to another in C?

Tags: c, function, c-strings, inverse

my program has two separate functions it excludes non-prime positions and then reserve the output from this. Except the issue I'm having is that at present it is not working how I want it to in the sense that the first function excludes the non prime places and then the second function uses the original input and reserves that instead of the output from function one. I'm new to C so please go easy on me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char[], long, long);
int main()
{
    char str[50];
    int i, j, k, cnt = 0;
    long size;

    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    size = strlen(str);
    reverse(str, 0, size - 1);
    printf(str);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char str[], long index, long size)
{
    char temp;
    temp = str[index];
    str[index] = str[size - index];
    str[size - index] = temp;
    if (index == size / 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    reverse(str, index + 1, size);
}
```

Sorry for being so vague, a sample output from an input of `1234567` would be `2357` then this output reversed into `7532`.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more your problem? In function `main`, you do not change `str` at all so in `reverse` you work with the original `str`.

Comment: Could you give an example input and the output that you expect? I don't really understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: *`excludes non-prime positions and then reserve the output`* -- What do you mean by *non-prime positions*? Possibly a typo for: *re**v**er**s**e the output*?

Comment: You changed the original in the function reverse. If you want to reuse the original. You should make a copy of that first and send that to the second function.
Not really a C problem, but more "common sense".

Comment: Hi Kamil,  say I inputted 123456 the first function would output 235 (As these are primes) and then reserve this. Likewise it does this with text, so hello would be elo and then ole when reversed.

Comment: how are elo the primes in hello???? But can I assume that the "prime-filter" works as intended and the problem is `reverse`? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: As in the prime positions, hello 12345 so where e is 2 would usually be which is prime where the first l is 3 would usually be which is also prime and where o is would usually be 5 which is itself prime. These functions work separately except I want the second function (reverse function) to take the output from my first function and reverse it instead of reversing the initial input. Thanks.

Comment: Explain a little more, str is never changed in main. I think you need to create a new array that will receive the characters that have non-prime position from original str. Beside that the way you check for prime numbers is wrong. Explain so that we can answer your question !

Comment: Okay your problem is not the reverse but the "filter".

Comment: So the input must be able to take numbered sequences and words?

Comment: Thanks Kami, I see what you mean. And yes RoadRunner.

Comment: @Ijustwanttolearn. Tip: Use `@` before a username if you want to notify them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what your code does (as it is written right now):

1. Input a string from console
2. Print out every character that is in a "prime position" (2, 3, 5, 7, etc) **without modifying the string**
3. Reverse the **original, unmodified** string
4. print out the reversed string

It sounds to me that what you are looking for is the following:
When you "exclude characters from a string" you create a *new string* that you populate with the characters from the input string that are in non-prime positions. Than you use that modified string as a parameter into the `reverse()` function.

I have no doubt that if you understand the above paragraph you'd have no problem fixing your code.

Here are the steps to achieve what you need:

1. input string into `str` (as you currently do)
2. introduce a **new string** `str2` of the same size `50` as the original string
3. in your loop copy every character from `str` into `str2` that is not in a "prime position"
4. call `reverse()` providing it the `str2` as a parameter, not the (current) `str`

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing yes, but struggling with how to pass the input. I know it's likely something so silly I'm doing wrong too.

Comment: @Ijustwanttolearn. as he said you do the filter and print it but you never save it into an array. Just create a new array and feed the filtered characters into it, THEN pass the NEW array to `reverse`.

Comment: Good analysis. But honestly: do you see any sense behind it?

Comment: @wolf just exercise? It could be worse.

Comment: OP's username is "I just want to learn", so this was obviously a learning assignment. Why not help then? ;-)

Comment: @YePhIcK concerning *`allocate a new string`*: couldn't this be also *declare/introduce another string variable*? Dynamic allocation would be new to this exercise, and there's no need to add that trap right now.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of the limitations. Let me update the answer

Comment: I think it's much better now. I don't know if those limitations really exist, but I prefer to fix problems in the simplest way possible.